# Why did the review warn me it might be spam after I closed it as spam?

Tags: support, review, spam

I just reviewed an answer on Travel. It was clearly spam and I flagged it as such. The moment I did, the review screen reloaded with the answer in red (because it had been deleted) and some stuff about being deleted by Community and so on. Above the now-deleted body was the warning:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

Duh! I just **flagged it as spam** dudes, I am on board with this.

All that was left for me to do was click <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> and wonder why I was given this warning after I had clearly reviewed carefully already.